# Laptop running very hot while playing games, looking for ways to improve temps

Tags: laptop, cpu, gpu, cooling, temperature

My friend has a Acer Aspire V 15 Nitro Black Edition VN7-593G-74J4 that he uses to play games like divinity. It has a GTX 1060 so built in, so the performance is good. The problem is the temperatures, which 85°c according to MSI afterburner. It is hot enough to make touching is uncomfortable. We are looking for solutions against this, like this [cooling pad](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NNMB3KS), but we first wanted to try something free. Afterburner doesnt allow any modifications, is there another way to modify the clock/voltage of the GPU? And would reducing the voltage of the CPU via intel XTU help? Any other tips?

Edit: The laptop is new, like 2 months old.

Comment: Cleaning the air vents may help in ways that surprise you.

Comment: Batteries and computer fans can be a simple ad-hoc way to keep things cool. https://youtu.be/2QM53-VbLtk

Comment: you can try a cooling pad.  In my experience, they dont help much.

Comment: Helpful info here: https://superuser.com/questions/1132759/alternative-methods-to-cool-laptop

Comment: I've had decent luck with cooling plates (though they may never be enough if the laptop OS prioritizes quiet over cool in its power management, or is poorly designed for heat evac), and put that on a cutting board, so that there is always good airflow to the plate intake and the underside of the laptop.

Answer (score 2):

For a laptop, and for a GPU, and especially for a laptop GPU, 85°C is actually a tolerable temperature - perhaps a little high, but nothing outrageous.  Desktop GPUs are typically set to speed their fans up only when the temperature reaches 80°C.

Bear in mind that this is the temperature of the die itself, which is the very hottest part.  Don't confuse it with the chassis temperature, which is what you're actually touching; if *that* was at 85°C, you'd have burns on your fingers.  That the heat is reaching the chassis in the first place shows that the interface between your CPU/GPU dies and their heatsinks is fine.

However, once heat gets into the heatsinks, it needs to get out again.  You'd prefer that to happen into the air more than into the chassis.  That means you need maximum airflow through the heatsinks, and that's what you should focus on improving.

PC laptops usually put the air intakes in the worst place imaginable - underneath.  That means you need to use it on a hard, flat surface (ie. a desk) to keep the intakes open.  Airflow to the underside can be improved further with a well-designed stand, but a typical "cooling pad" will actually suck air *away* from the underside, which is counterproductive.  Even if your laptop has intakes on the sides, a cooling pad may have little effect if the base is made of plastic.  (It makes more sense with a Mac, as those have solid, metal bases with no intakes, so an inward external airflow helps to cool the whole machine.)

Regardless of where the intakes and vents are, make sure they're not clogged with dust.  Also ensure that the fans are running properly, and look for ways to make them run faster when things get warm inside.